# Post method in Solr.Net

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I am using a solr.net in my C# application. To get the result I am using the below query in the solr.

```
 solr.Query(query, queryOptions);
```

The problem is that, when we have a very long query and then we execute this command that time it produce an error, since it is using Get method and there a liming in the query string of the Get method. Is there any why by which we can use the Post method ?

Answer (score 1):

Please see this blog post - [Customizing SolrNet](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/12/customizing-solrnet.html) from the SolrNet author that describes how to create a custom `PostSolrConnection` class.